# Why is Word 2007 not allowing me to select and edit text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I have just installed Office 2007 for a user.  Word is acting strangely.  If I open a document.  The cursor just stays at the top left of the document and I can not place it anywhere else.  I cannot select other text.  I cannot write additional text.

If I simply open up Word and start a new document I am allowed to type like normal.  If I were to save and close this document and reopen it.  I would not be able to input anything.

Seems like I am stuck in some wrong input mode?

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the document locked or read-only?

Comment: No the document is not locked or read-only.

Comment: Can you open the mentioned document in some other word processing program (google docs maybe) ? Can it be saved under a different name and then reopened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was specific to user profile.  The problem did not exist while signed on with a different domain user profile.  I simply backed up the users files.  Deleted her profile.  Restored profile.  Restored files.

Problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your documents are all defaulting to read-only. What does the title bar read when you open the document you can't edit?